# Is a block a statement in Java?

Tags: java

This could apply to other languages but asking specific to Java. In Java would a block itself be a statement? In the Java tutorials: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html a block is treated separately from a statement by saying it is a sequence/group of statements but does not say it is a statement itself. Can someone please also explain why.

Comment: why does it concern you to consider a block as a statement? are you making a compiler or something?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, according to the grammar defined in the Java Language Specification ([§14.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5)), a `Block` is a kind of `Statement`, specifically it is a `StatementWithoutTrailingSubstatement`.

Answer (score 2):

See JLS §14.5 (see other answer). Also, in both ecj and javac (the two most popular java parsers/compilers out there):

- Javac's AST node representing a block: [JCBlock](https://java-browser.yawk.at/java/11/jdk.compiler/com/sun/tools/javac/tree/JCTree.java#com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree.JCBlock), the AST node that represents a block, extends JCStatement.
- ecj's: [Block](https://git.eclipse.org/c/e4/org.eclipse.jdt.core.git/tree/compiler/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/ast/Block.java) extends `Statement`.

So, the spec says it is a statement, and both major implementations represent it as a subtype of its version of Statement.